# how to ignore bash event designator when it appears in command line?

Tags: bash

`echo "!omg"` outputs `-bash: !omg: event not found`

1. How I can output `!omg` string to console?
2. My problem arises because I need to execute some node code using command line:

   `node -e "var code = function(){ console.log('which contains a lot of !'); }; !func();"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes:

```
echo '!omg'
```

If you have quotes in your input, e.g. to print `console.log('lalala')`, say:

```
echo $'console.log(\'lalala\')'
```

Alternatively, say:

```
cat | command << EOF
my_string_with_crazy_characters
EOF
```

The last form wouldn't require you to escape any character in the input.

Comment: It works but it also strips any `'` in the string so `echo 'console.log('lalala')'` prints `console.log(lalala)` instead of `console.log('lalala')` - is there any workaround for this? I have to pass javascript code so many different characters may appear in source... And I cant load script from file.

Comment: @user606521 See edit above.

Comment: You could also prefer printf to echo  (it's more portable!) : `printf '%s\n' "$something"` will print the content of $something variable.

Comment: @OlivierDulac It's a chicken and egg problem.  The problem is essentially about getting quotes and crazy characters as is.  In that event, the `cat` solution would be ideal as it obviates the need of escaping the input.

Answer (score 1):

You could turn off `history expansion` as follows

```
[username@hostname ~]$ set +o histexpand
[username@hostname ~]$ echo hello!world!anything
hello!world!anything
```

to turn on

```
[username@hostname ~]$ set -o histexpand
[username@hostname ~]$ echo hello!world!anything
-bash: !world!anything: event not found
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to unset the shell variable `histchars` to effectively disable history expansion:

```
$ echo !omg
bash: !omg: event not found
$ histchars=
$ echo !omg
!omg
```